# Lego D11 ripper cylinder

Tags: technic, building

I'm building the Lego set [42131 D11 bulldozer](https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/app-controlled-cat-d11-bulldozer-42131) and my back ripper cylinders (linear actuators) are in the complete up position and it's keeping me from completing the build.

How do you get them to go down? I tried the control on my phone but it just keeps calibrating and won’t move past that screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the length (extension) of linear actuators manually in two ways:

- The same motor would do - by rotating the axle on its end.
- By rotating an extending shaft. Just make sure the other end is fixed, otherwise it would spin freely without doing anything.